# Is it possible to get the current total Twitter followers number? and how often?

Tags: twitter

Here is the thing. I'd like to set up a counter that shows total number of Twitter followers for a user. When the number of followers reach exactly 1,000,000, would love to do something. If there's an api to do that, how often can I call the api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello
Sorry I don't know PHP that well, and not at all JQuery, however, here is what I've done in C# ... hope it helps ;)

```
// Launch the request to obtain the number of followers of the user
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=[username]");

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

// Load response in an XML Document
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(streamReader.ReadToEnd());

// Parse the node we're interested in...
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("followers_count");

// ... and affect the number of followers
labelScore.Text = node.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. I can use other properties as well to extract from the xmldoc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [users/show](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show) call to get this information. You'll find it as a property named `followers_count`:

```
"followers_count": 160752,
```

Comment: Awesome. How can I retrieve the followers_count property then? You have a simple example. Appreciated. Using jquery or php or whatever you like.